# Оverflow evaluating the requirement, Rust Traits

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I am trying to write a trait which requires an inner type Iter. And Iter should implements Iterator. I am getting such error "overflow evaluating the requirement `<str as SomeTrait>::Iter == _`" and can't understand what it wants. Can anybody help to understand ?)

```
pub trait SomeIter { 
   type Iter where Self::Iter: Iterator;
}

struct NumberIter(u32, u8);

impl Iterator for NumberIter {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.1 == 32 || (self.0 >> self.1) == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let ret = ((self.0 >> self.1) as u8) & 0xFF;
            self.1 += 8;
            Some(ret)
        }
    }
}

impl SomeTrait for str {
    type Iter = NumberIter;
}
```

The compiler advised reading some examples in https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0275 but there weren't similar ones.

Comment: [Repro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9065b6034ddf5a383d10a86a31028f53)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the resolution over the `where Self::Iter` part (because it is recursive), where you just really need to constrain the type:

```rust
pub trait SomeIter { 
   type Iter: Iterator;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e024757966ee105e6ff2e066d245d557)

Comment: It worked, thank you. I was adding `where Self::Iter` because the compiler was advising.

Comment: @YakobsSaghatelyan [No it doesn't?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3ac862d1d2943b7cf008560bad90cfe)